# Why is my crontab not executing?

Tags: python, shell, amazon-s3, cron

So I have a shell script that is executing my python file.  The file is uploading to an S3 bucket. I want to set a cron for this to run every hour. The python file and shell script both execute correctly when called separately and upload successfully to S3, so I'm guessing the problem is with my crontab as nothing gets uploaded to S3 every hour. I am running this on a red hat instance. I set my crontab using:

crontab -e

0 * * * * /path/to/shell/script

Then I can confirm it's there by doing: crontab -l

I should also mention this was working correctly before but I modified my script some and now it won't run. I have checked the permissions to the path and of both the python file and shell script and they should be able to execute. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: What did you change in the script?

Comment: I meant to say I changed up my python file not script. I changed it so that the uploading the file to S3 was done in the same in the same python file my code was running in. Like I said though the python file and shell script work correctly when executed it's just when I set a crontab it doesn't work.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions on this - check your shebang is correct, check your PATH is correct, check your script is executable, check your environment variables. Temporarily change the script to `touch` a file in `/tmp` to see if it runs at all...

Comment: I got the crontab to execute; however, I ran into another problem.  In my shell script I have two python files being executed. The first one creates a file, the second one uploads that file to S3. When I execute the shell script on it's own it work correctly. When I set it to run on a cron, only the second python script executes, meaning a file is uploaded to S3 (however the first python script doesn't execute, so an old file is being uploaded to S3). What can be the cause of this? only one python file being executed through the crone.